# How to create a smooth animation for my menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a menu that expands "on hover" but the problem is that if I hover over an item , and that item is running an animation **the next** item animation will not be smooth (basically sub-menu will show up in the middle of animation).

I have created [a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6Hbs/) of the problem.

I think that this part of my code is causing the issue:

```
j('.active').next('ul')
.removeClass('sub-menu')
.addClass('jsub-menu').css({
'visibility':'',
'opacity':'',
'height':get_height_of_first_child +'px',
'width':'0'
 });
j('.active').next('.jsub-menu').animate({width:get_width},2000);

j('.active').next('.jsub-menu').animate({height:get_submenu_height},2000);
```

Edit: Here is the updated [Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/m6Hbs/). If you look closely on line `59` I have added this code

`if(j('.active').next('.jsub-menu').is(':animated')){
j('.active').next('.jsub-menu').hide();
}`

Now if you hover over an **"Hover me while I am expanding!"** and that menu is animated it will hide the menu (don't want that but bear with me).

So now try to hover over an **"Hover me" only** and **WAIT 4-5 seconds** and **THEN** hover over **"Hover me while I am expanding!"** you will see that next menu animates smoothly.

This is the effect I want but obviously I do not want to hide the menu in the process.

Comment: What is the result you want to see? If the item running an animation is still running, did you want that animation to complete before the next one, or did you want the next one to start showing up even when the previous one hasn't finished animating?

Comment: Yes I want to start second animation after the first one is finished...

Comment: I would suggest (if possible) reworking the navigation, too many levels are annoying and you run into the problem of accidental mouseOut and then they have t go through the whole thing again. I suggest hopping over to the UX stack exchange (http://ux.stackexchange.com/) to look for some ways to simplify the menu for a better user experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. It checks to see if it is the direct sub menu of the parent `.jnav` and uses `slideDown` if so. Otherwise it gets the width (while the element has `visibility:hidden`) and animates it to that width after

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();    
j(document).ready(function () {    
    j('ul.nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('jnav');    
    j('ul.jnav li').hover(function () {
        if (j(this).children('ul:first').hasClass('jsub-menu')) { 
            return false; 
        } else {    
            if(j('ul.jnav > li').is(this)) {
                j(this).find('ul.sub-menu:first').not(':animated').slideDown(500);
            } else {
                var elem = j(this).find('ul.sub-menu:first').not(':animated');
                elem.css({
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    display: 'block'                    
                });
                var elemWidth = elem.width();
                console.log(elemWidth);
                elem.css({
                    width: '0px',
                    visibility: 'visible'
                }).animate({
                    width: elemWidth
                });
            }
        }
    }, function () {
        j(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(500, function () {
            j(this).removeClass('jsub-menu').addClass('sub-menu');            
        });
    });    
});
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/m6Hbs/3/)

Comment: Yes this works but as you may noticed in my example I do not want that every item slides down, only the first one. So only the first sub-menu slides down , all others must animate width ,then check if there are children and then animate height.

Comment: @DejoDekic Updated to fix that issue

Comment: Don't worry :) I will accept your answer but I need to wait 20 hours to award you the bounty;)

Comment: @DejoDekic There was no need for that! I was perfectly happy with what I had!

Comment: There you go;) I didn't award you right away because I was wanted to see a couple of more answers or suggestions... Anyway THX @Zack for help and nice coding.